# Why Eulers' totient doesn't seem to work in following situation?

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function

I have a question about Eulers' totient function related to RSA

(1) $N=PQ$

(2) $\varphi(N)=\varphi(P)\varphi(Q)=(P-1)(Q-1)$

Now, say $P = 3$ and $Q = 3$

From (1) it follows that $N=PQ=3\cdot3=9$

From (2) it follows that $\varphi(9)=\varphi(3)\varphi(3)=(3-1)(3-1)=2\cdot2=4$

But, actually $6$ numbers are coprime with $9$, being $1,2,4,5,7,8$, so actually $\varphi(9)=6$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Suppose $p$ is a prime, then you can easily count the coprimes of $p^n$ and can find that $\varphi(p^n) = p^n - p^{n-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation $\varphi(pq)=\varphi(p)\varphi(q)$ is only true if $\gcd(p,q)=1$. But here $\gcd(p,q)=\gcd(3,3)=3$.

Hence the two primes that multiply to $N$ in the RSA cryptosystem must be *distinct*.